# How to use repeated components of master stack template for multiple parameters in a child stack template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nested, stack, aws-cloudformation

I'm created a nested stack and essentially want to apply the same base stack resource format to multiple cases, however, I'm not sure how to translate that to the cloudformation template script.

For instance, in the following (un-nested) stack template, I have several Lambda function parameters that all use the same base format for a lambda function resource and lambda function execution role resource:

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: "Master template for wgs-pipeline. Calls to other stack templates."
Parameters:
  CloudspanLambdaFuncS3BucketName:
    Type: String
  CloudspanLambdaFuncS3KeyName:
    Default: 'sfn.deployable.zip'
    Type: String
  CloudspanLambdaFuncModuleName:
    Default: 'cloudspan'
    Type: String
  AlignmentLambdaFuncS3BucketName:
    Type: String
  AlignmentLambdaFuncS3KeyName:
    Type: String
  AlignmentLambdaFuncModuleName:
    Type: String
Resources:
  CloudspanLambdaExecutionRole:
  Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
  Properties:
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
      Version: "2012-10-17"
      Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
          Action: "sts:AssumeRole"
    Policies:
      - PolicyName: CanListBuckets
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - "s3:GetBucketLocation"
                - "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
              Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::*"
      - PolicyName: CanLog
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
            - logs:*
            Resource: arn:aws:logs:*:*:*

CloudspanLambdaFunction:
  Type: "AWS::Lambda::Function"
  Properties:
    Handler:
      Fn::Join: [ ".", [ Ref: CloudspanLambdaFuncModuleName, "handler"] ]
    Role:
      Fn::GetAtt: [ CloudspanLambdaExecutionRole, Arn ]
    Code:
      S3Bucket:
        Ref: CloudspanLambdaFuncS3BucketName
      S3Key:
        Ref: CloudspanLambdaFuncS3KeyName
    Runtime: "python3.6"
    Timeout: "60"

AlignmentLambdaExecutionRole:
  Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
  Properties:
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
      Version: "2012-10-17"
      Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
          Action: "sts:AssumeRole"
    Policies:
      - PolicyName: CanListBuckets
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - "s3:GetBucketLocation"
                - "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
              Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::*"
      - PolicyName: CanCallBatch
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - "batch:*"
              Resource: "*"
      - PolicyName: CanLog
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
            - logs:*
            Resource: arn:aws:logs:*:*:*

AlignmentLambdaFunction:
  Type: "AWS::Lambda::Function"
  Properties:
    Handler:
      Fn::Join: [ ".", [ Ref: AlignmentLambdaFuncModuleName, "handler"] ]
    Role:
      Fn::GetAtt: [ AlignmentLambdaExecutionRole, Arn ]
    Code:
      S3Bucket:
        Ref: AlignmentLambdaFuncS3BucketName
      S3Key:
        Ref: AlignmentLambdaFuncS3KeyName
    Runtime: "python3.6"
    Timeout: "60"
```

You can see that there are some differences, for e.g. in the PolicyNames between the lambda function resources, as well as the parameters they reference.

My question is, if I separate the above master template such that the Lambda function resources are in a child template, how can I apply the same base resource format across all those parameters (CloudspanLambda, AlignmentLambda, etc.)?

Below is an example of how I've set up my **child template** so far.

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: lambda function and execution role stack.
Parameters:
  {x}LambdaFuncS3BucketName:
    Type: String
  {x}LambdaFuncS3KeyName:
    Type: String
  {x}LambdaFuncModuleName:
    Type: String
Resources:
  LambdaFunction:
    Type: "AWS::Lambda::Function"
    Properties:
      Handler:
        Fn::Join: [ ".", [ Ref: {x}LambdaFuncModuleName, "handler"] ]
      Role:
        Fn::GetAtt: [ {x}LambdaExecutionRole, Arn ]
      Code:
        S3Bucket:
          Ref: {x}LambdaFuncS3BucketName
        S3Key:
          Ref: {x}LambdaFuncS3KeyName
      Runtime: "python3.6"
  LambdaExecutionRole:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action: "sts:AssumeRole"
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: CanListBuckets
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - "s3:GetBucketLocation"
                  - "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
                Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        - PolicyName: CanLog
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
              - logs:*
              Resource: arn:aws:logs:*:*:*
```

I've put `{x}`'s in there for now to represent the iterable for all those parameters essentially. I'll also need to vary the use of PolicyNames, depending on which Lambda function is being referenced.  What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is sample template to give you an idea.

**Master.yaml:**

```
Resources:
  Cloudspan:
    Type: "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack"
    Properties:
      Parameters:
        LambdaName: Cloudspan
        BucketName: <BucketName>
        S3KeyName: <S3KeyName>
        FunctionName: <FunctionName>
      TemplateURL: <TemplateURL>
  Alignment:
    Type: "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack"
    Properties:
      Parameters:
        LambdaName: Alignment
        BucketName: <BucketName>
        S3KeyName: <S3KeyName>
        FunctionName: <FunctionName>
      TemplateURL: <TemplateURL>
```

**Lambda-child.yaml:**

```
Parameters:
  LambdaName:
    Type: String
  BucketName:
    Type: String
  S3KeyName:
    Type: String
  FunctionName:
    Type: String

Resources:
  LambdaFunction:
    Type: "AWS::Lambda::Function"
    Properties:
      Handler: !Sub '${LambdaName}-{FunctionName}.Handler'
      Role:
        Fn::GetAtt: [!Sub '${LambdaName}LambdaExecutionRole', Arn ]
      Code:
        S3Bucket: !Sub '${LambdaName}{BucketName}'
        S3Key: !Sub '${LambdaName}{S3KeyName}'
      Runtime: "python3.6"
```

Comment: Thank you, @Sudharsan! This is very helpful.

Comment: Yes, it should be surrounded by ${} '${LambdaName}${ExecutionRole}'

Comment: When I try to create the stack, I get an error saying `Template error: every Fn::GetAtt object requires two non-empty parameters, the resource name and the resource attribute`, which is pointing to the line with `Fn::GetAtt` above in the **Lambda-child.yaml**